# Fix Eclipse / SpringToolSuite4 Ubuntu 22.04 wide header bar

Tags: eclipse, spring-tool-suite, ubuntu-22.04

Eclipse, Version: 2022-03 (4.23.0) & SpringToolSuite4, Version: 4.14.1.RELEASE has too wide header bar (window bar) and incorrectly scaled window UI buttons.

Other applications like VS Code & Android Studio are rendered correctly. On a screen below on a right side you can see SpringToolSuite4 window with incorrect header bar render and on left side there is AndroidStudio with correctly rendered header bar.

How I can fix Header Bar for STS / Eclipse for Ubuntu 22.04 without downgrading to Ubuntu 20.04?

[image]

Comment: Does setting `GTK_THEME` help? https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.8/platform.php#gtk3-theme-override-support

Comment: Nope, setting `GTK_THEME=Adwaita:dark` or `GTK_THEME=Adwaita` as env variable did not help

Comment: Could you please tell the GTK version used and tell whether it looks different when using a fresh workspace.

Comment: Not sure what you exactly mean. It looks to me like the width of the window on the right screenshot is not wide enough to contain all the actions/icons, so it appears as a second row of icons (like a line break) - which is the expected behavior in Eclipse. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: Added red arrows to screen to highlight what I mean.

Comment: `$gtk-launch --version` outputs `3.24.33`. The same issue happens when I open fresh workspace.